# Could an aircraft have squashable wings that get thicker as it flies faster?

Tags: airliner, wing

As I understand, for high speed subsonic flight a thicker wing is more aerodynamic, and at low speed, a thin wing is preferable. Could aircraft which range in speed from 180 to 620 knots (most commercial airliners) have wings which can compress to be thicker during high speed flight? This would be controlled either by a mechanical system to change its shape or just by the oncoming wind pushing it into shape.

Comment: What you mention seems to be called called variable thickness wing morphing. See those two papers for instance (if you have access) https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0376042117301835 https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/1.37073. I think this technology is currently limited to demonstrators, but I can't be sure of course.

Comment: Conventional lore has it the other way round, that a thick wing is better at 180 kt and a thin wing is better at 620 kt. What are your reasons for believing it is the other way round?

Comment: I took a free smithstonian course on aerodynamics and recall that thinner wings are better for low speed flight, and that this was figured out in the forties or something, when the jet engine allowed planes to fly much faster. I may be wrong